# Why does each HashMap leaf node contain key-value tuple?

Tags: scala, hashmap

I am trying to understand the `HashMap` implementation. This is how a leaf node is declared:

```
class HashMap1[A, B](
    val key: A,
    val value: B,
    val hash: Int,
    var kv: (A, B)
) extends HashMap[A, B]
```

The first three fields are OK. But the last `kv` field is just a tuple containing the key and the value.

For me, this looks like a waste of space (the size of the pointer to the tuple + the size of the tuple). Why do we need to store an extra field which can easily be calculated on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "time of creation" this pair is more valuable than "used memory" in this case.

`kv` used as a cache, and it is `var` because can be filled on demand, and this looks resonable in case if `Merger` use this key value pair frequently and `key` & `value` are immutable and can be passed to new `HashMap1` as is and after used for next merge stage.